# Arranging the ports in the element diagram in the EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have 5 ports in the diagram element .When we add the ports to the element through addin we found that all the ports are placed one above another.So we tried to arrange them through the co-ordinates that are provided for the diagram objects.But still we are not able to arrange them properly.So is there any way we can arrange the ports in the element such that it should be placed properly in the elements border without overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to upgrade EA. This functionality has been buggy with former EA versions. (AFAIR 10 and 11 suffered from this)